# Android Studio I keep getting Gradle error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can import a sample app project, try to build it and I keep getting this error. Not always the same file but a new temp file each time. I've tried several different samples. I've been programming for 30+ years and feel completely clueless. Only clue seems to be the Windows Task Manager shows 99% to 100% CPU usage when it gives the error and ends the build.

Comment: Can you possibly debug on another computer? Is this a new problem for this computer (meaning was Android Studio previously installed on this computer previously and able to build successfully, or have you never gotten it to successfully build)? It might be helpful to include your JDK and Android Studio versions.

Comment: Apparently, something is locked and it might be a file or a network port such as the one used by the gradle daemon. Please post the error message and surrounding build log details. Also try rebooting, since that'll free up other processes and other Windows state. After rebooting, does it work once? Repeatedly?

Comment: Rebooted, tried it, same type of error. Uninstalled everything to do with Android Studio, download latest bundle from developer.android.com, installed it, created new project from Android Sample ActionBarCompat-Styled, it automatically tried to build the project, and I got a similar error: see next for actual error message

Comment: 7:54:56 PM Gradle sync started
7:55:00 PM Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\bewert\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts-remapped\asLocalRepo404_39k6fuo680j1lkxpf4phfc2zr\eapmmo6ilx21t7xdau0amjhgn\init57408229\classes\asLocalRepo404_39k6fuo680j1lkxpf4phfc2zr$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure4.class (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Comment: Exited Android Studio, renamed .gradle folder in my User folder, restarted Android Studio, it loaded the ActionBarCompat-Styled project and tried to build it. Same type of error, see in message below

Comment: 9:10:25 PM Gradle sync started
9:11:49 PM Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\bewert\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts\eapmmo6ilx21t7xdau0amjhgn\init\init57408229\classes\_BuildScript_$_run_closure1$_closure3.class (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
           Consult IDE log for more details

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\bewert\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo432.gradle' from cache.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\bewert\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts-remapped\asLocalRepo432_4wmjqiqyxcwg0uqwt4edorrs2\eapmmo6ilx21t7xdau0amjhgn\init57408229\classes\asLocalRepo432_4wmjqiqyxcwg0uqwt4edorrs2$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6.class (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) NOTE: the file is there

Comment: @BruceE, please move your comments into the body of the question.  Makes for easier reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution ? Because every answer solve the issue but I would like to avoid do this for every build

Answer (score 72):

Do This

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. -> Invalidate/ Restart**

Comment: but again after working once it shows the same error. can we avoid doing this after every build . I  am facing this issue after every successful build and has to invalid and restart.

Comment: Clean (Build -> Clean Project) is much faster than invalidate and worked for me. If Clean didn't solve your problem, then invalidate Caches and watch a movie.

Comment: yah don't want to have to restart every single time. This happens every time I try to run the application on the virtual or real device.

Comment: Killing `java.exe` process, which somehow left running after the previous build, fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 43):

When this happens to me on Windows 8, I open the task manager

[image: task manager]

and simply kill all the instances of "openjdk platform binary"

edit Feb 2024:
from powershell I now use this command to kill openjdk (java):

```
 Get-Process -Name "java" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: yah i did this, but it keeps coming back. I don't want to have to keep doing this. I need a solution.

Comment: Use  "./gradlew clean" in the terminal

Comment: @PrasaDev Hi, yes I tried that but it did not work. For me only killing those tasks worked

Comment: @wesleyfranks We have no choice but to accept that when a Java process is launched during the build, some files may be unable to be properly unlocked so killing the offending process is the only way to release the lock.

Answer (score 9):

Just clean the project and have a run ! It would work ....

Comment: yah having to do this every time I run the app... no fix still does it. Re-installed Android studio even tried other versions still the same...

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Choose `app` instead of `DefaultPreview`. Now if you build, then you should not see this issue.

Comment: Android Studio might switch it from app to DefaultPreview if you click on 'Run Preview' in design or split mode.

Answer (score 4):

Invalidating the IDE cache is NOT enough.

0. To delete the folder `app\build` we should first stop locking process - OpenJDK Platform binary.
1. **Delete the folder** `app\build`
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart...

---

*Context*: Using Coroutines in Android Instrumented Test.

GL

Comment: Agree. To delete the folder we should first stop locking process - OpenJDK Platform binary.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue's.Even I tried all the solution mentioned here it didn't work.Even I can't delete the signin file as running android studio administrative mode.I see a notification at bottom right side of the IDE update gradle pluggin.So update gradle pluggin usually worked for me[image]

Comment: yeah - I had the same problem - old gradle version caused an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Kill task "openjdk platform binary" works for me

Answer (score 2):

Restart of Android Studio with cache invalidation doesn't help.
As others said, we should delete a `<module>\build` folder. Because a file is locked by `OpenJDK Platform binary`, we should stop this process in Task Manager (or unlock the file via [LockHinter](https://lockhunter.com/)).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case it is due to multiple Java Run times (JRE's). Try switching between JRE's in android studio or use only one Java runtime.

Hope it fix the problem. Happy Coding..

[image]

Comment: in my particular case I have JDK 11 everywhere as the source/target compatibility version, but for some reason Android Studio keeps picking my JDK 8 installation by default for Gradle.  If I go to File -> Settings -> Build. Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle JDK and set the JDK to the Embedded JDK, this problem seems to go away.

Comment: ...actually scratch that, the JDK setting alone didn't do the trick.  I was running an instrumented test suite and it turned out the process was kept running by the IDE even after the test suite completed.  I just hit the red square in Android Studio to stop it and then I was able to re-run the test suite without the locked file issue.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate Caches / Restart doesn't work all the time and it's not the better idea to close the whole Android Studio just we couldn't figure out what process was using it.

Please follow the below steps to figure out which process is using your file.

You can use the Resource Monitor for this which comes built-in with Windows 7, 8, and 10.

1. Open Resource Monitor, which can be found
   By searching for Resource Monitor or resmon.exe in the start menu, or
   As a button on the Performance tab in your Task Manager
2. Go to the CPU tab
3. Use the search field in the Associated Handles section

When you've found the handle, you can identify the process by looking at the Image and/or PID column.

You can then try to close the application as you normally would, or, if that's not possible, just right-click the handle and kill the process directly from there.

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

If the error is recurring, you can try a file leak detector to determine what part of the gradle process is holding your files. As suggested [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167701947),

1. Download [file leak detector](https://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/)
2. Check with resmon what process is holding on to the file
3. Depending on where the file is locked, do the following:

   - Android Studio: In studio, go to `Help` → `Edit custom VM options` and add the following line:

     ```
     -javaagent:path/to/file-leak-detector.jar=http=19999
     ```
   - Gradle: Add to your gradle.properties file the following line:

     ```
     org.gradle.jvmargs=-javaagent:path/to/file-leak-detector.jar=http=19999
     ```
4. When the problem occurs again, open `localhost:19999` in your browser and search for locked files.

---

In my case, I found out that a file was held by AspectJ compiler/weaver (ajc):

```
#115 C:\Users\me\StudioProjects\myapp\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar by thread:Execution worker for ':' Thread 3 on Mon Oct 19 18:41:06 BST 2020
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:156)
    ...
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
```

I was running it directly from Gradle:

```
new Main().run(args, handler)
```

I don't know if it's possible to make ajc release the files. So I resolved my issue by running it in a separate process. I added a new configuration to get aspectjtools onto classpath:

```kotlin
val weaving: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    weaving("org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.6")
}
```

And instead of the above code, I did:

```kotlin
javaexec {
    classpath = weaving
    main = "org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main"
    args = arguments
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to delete the file (the folder inside builder message)
the message will contain process name ( i dont remember the name)
find the prcess in task manager and stop it

Answer (score 1):

Terminating "OpenJDK platform binary" from Task Manager then deleting src/build and finally rebuilding the project should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Above suggested solutions may fixed this error but they are time consuming so the best solution to fix this problem is open command prompt and run the following command.

```
taskkill /im java.exe /f
```

[image: screenshot of command prompt]

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 jre's installed when I installed android studio. Uninstall the one that you find from control panel and that is located something like c:\program files\java etc.

On the next opening of android studio 4.0 + it will fallback to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" and the process lockdown after each succesfull build will stop

Answer (score 0):

For those which are still searching for this answer in 2022, **remove** the build folder and **rebuild**...

Comment: This doesn't help for long.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same on Windows 10, it was resolved by **closing all "Command Prompt"** (cmd) windows ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the /.gradle/ directory and rebuilding resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using External Emulator:

Restarting Android Studio with cache invalidation doesn't helped.

The file that caused the problem is being used by the emulator and if you are using an external emulator (BlueStacks) like me, restarting Android Studio will not help. I restarted the emulator and the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

It happened me many times while building or Cleaning the Project
The solution is simple:

1. Open the Specific Directory
2. Close the Android Studio
3. Delete the particular Directory
4. Now run the Android Studio