# Error on signing-config.json (Access is denied) running an app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to run my app but I got this error in the android studio:

> D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ShelfExpert\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json
>   (Access is denied)

What should I do?

Comment: what is that singing-config.json i mean take a look at keystore.properties in root folder and make sure evrything is correct

Comment: You should expand your question with some possible related information first.

Comment: flutter clean
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used

Answer (score 131):

Just Delete the File signing_config.json and re-run

And it will work fine

Comment: works for me too. Is that file responsible for error

Comment: Running Android Studio as administrator didn't work for me, I even tried granting full access to that file but didn't work either, I had to delete the file which was promptly recreated on next build. The issue happened to me after my local account was joint to a domain (work PC)

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete 'D:\example\User App\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json'

Comment: check the answer here--https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789519/6995566

Comment: Funny. I thought on deleting the file too, but checked here on StackOverflow first just to be sure.

Comment: Worked for me too.  But this is so weird, I was running Android Studio as Administrator when the error occurred.

Answer (score 33):

Simply, just run your Android Studio as Administrator and it will do the trick and no need to delete any file or anything. This worked for me.

Comment: There is an option to always run Android Studio as administrator. So that issue would be gone forever. Example for windows: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/

Comment: no need to delete signing_config.json this is real answer thanksssss.....

Answer (score 25):

In Some cases, it will not allow you to remove the file just by pressing "Delete" button.

You need to use "Shift + Delete"

Answer (score 17):

```
app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json
```

In my case, I followed the most voted answer in this question.

After delete `signing-config.json` file in the above path, everything works fine!:)

Comment: You upvote the answer that worked for you instead of adding your own answer

Comment: @Leo I thought it might be better to leave full path for sigining-config.json at that time. So, I need to leave a comment something in addition to upvoting. And I didn't have any reputation which enables me to leave comments, so this own answer was created. Your comment totally makes sense now for me :)

Comment: That path helped me

Answer (score 6):

Run Android Studio in Administrator mode and the problem gone..
Just right click on android studio icon and click on "Run as Administrator"

You can also set the app to always run as administrator by [this method](https://www.blogger.com/u/1/blogger.g?blogID=1361180429125888108#editor/target=post;postID=6438728760886465880;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname)

Answer (score 5):

You might not be the owner of the file.

If that's the case, you can't delete `signing-config.json`

You can fix it by claiming ownership to the file if you're an admin.
[Try following the instructions here from the answer to claim ownership.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0d5d4c0-c11c-435a-aa2d-83388e3bd2d2/i-am-an-administrator-but-i-keep-getting-errors-like-quotyou-require-permission-from?forum=w7itprosecurity)

I fixed mine by giving permission to `Users`.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the signing_config.json from the respective directory will resolve the issue

Answer (score 4):

1. Open cmd(if on windows) as administrator
2. Move to the "signing-config.json" location in cmd. In my case location was "E:\AndroidStudioProjects\my-project\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out."
3. run command del signing-config.json

Don't forget to clean and rebuild project.

Done.

Answer (score 4):

Just Delete the signingconfig.json file and re-run the app. Run as administrator. You can find the signingconfig.json in build/intermediate.

Answer (score 4):

Just run this command while you are running the emulator

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 3):

Working solution for me:

**Step: 1**
Run your **Android studio** as `Run as administrator`.

**Step: 2**
Delete app → `build` folder

**Step: 3**
`Clean` and `rebuild` your project and chill

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem, but I use React-Native. I was trying to build a release version of my app (with the 'gradlew assembleRelease' command). Deleting this file haven't solved the problem. To solve I had to set the user permission of the file **explicity** to my user (even beeing  the current admin) on Windows. In other words I gave permission of reading and writing. You can do that by going in the Properties of the file. Previously, everything was working fine and after some updates this started to happen. I think Windows have made some mess with something. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Once when I had the problem, it turned out to be because of the network drive on which the project was stored. For some reason, the file permission on the network drive was preventing this particular file access, and hence the error - even after a clean build. Moving the project from the network drive to the local drive solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact same error while trying to build a project located on an exFAT partition. I think our problem simply has to have something in common regarding to permissions because exFAT file system does not store file permissions whatsoever (all files premissions appear to be 777).

It is worth noting, that exFAT file system was designed to be universal between almost all operating systems, and was not oriented on performance or anything else.

Comment: Is there a solution to this? Have you found a way to run it from an exFAT partition?

Comment: @KellinStrook I'm still not sure. I just gave up on this

Answer (score 1):

Sometime clean and rebuild the project will clear the error

Answer (score 1):

Just open `signing-config.json`. You can find it by going to the `project level`, and just change `SigningEnabled` from `true` to `false`. e.g.: `"mV1SigningEnabled":true`, `"mV2SigningEnabled":true` to `"mV1SigningEnabled":false`, `"mV2SigningEnabled":false`.

Answer (score 1):

What I am going to provide may not be the proper solution of this problem. I encountered the same problem and I resolved it by opening the android studio again as an administrator. I hope this works in your case as well.