# Cant run android project. I get error : signing-config.json

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm update my android studio to 3.4.2. But after that I can't run my android project. I get error signing-config.json

I have following the instruction from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721361/when-i-run-the-app-i-get-this-error-signing-config-json-access-is-denied) SO question to delete signing-config.json file. But I cant, because I don't have a permission although I have login into administrator user.

I expect to run my android studio

[image]

Comment: Please provide build.gradle file code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Delete the File signing_config.json and re-run

And it will work fine

Comment: i cant delete that file. I dont have permission although i have log in into administrator

Comment: i also cant delete that file. I dont have permission although i have log in into administrator

Comment: Simply, just run your Android Studio as Administrator and it will do the trick and no need to delete any file or anything. This worked for me.

app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json

In my case, I followed the most voted answer in this question.

After delete signing-config.json file in the above path, everything works fine!:)

Comment: @Jackeykabra Doesn't work anymore